# GNU Radio Radar Toolbox

Tags: gnuradio

I am trying to download the GNU Radio Radar Toolbox from this link(https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-radar). I followed the steps listed in that link, but when I reach the {cmake ../} it gives that:

```
-- Checking for module 'gmp'
--   No package 'gmp' found
```

and

```
-- Checking for module 'Qt5Qwt6'
--   No package 'Qt5Qwt6' found
```

When I started searching how to download the Qt, I noticed that is not free. Also,  some of the online commands (shown below) don't solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install qt5-doc
sudo apt-get install qt5-doc-html qtbase5-doc-html
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-examples
```

Any idea how to solve the problem of these two packages?

Answer (score 0):

To build GNU Radio Radar Toolbox on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS you have install GRC 3.8 from [GNU Radio PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnuradio/+archive/ubuntu/gnuradio-releases-3.8) and the build-dependencies by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential gnuradio-dev qtbase5-dev libuhd-dev doxygen graphviz swig libqwt-qt5-dev texlive-latex-base texlive-binaries
```

and then compile using the following commands

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-radar.git
cd gr-radar
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j$(nproc)

sudo ./../examples/setup/setup_core
ctest
sudo make install
```

Comment: I already downloaded the GNU Radio 3.8 on my pc.
Do I need the first two lines?

Comment: This answer is written in completely reproducible form for fresh 18.04 LTS installation. In your case you can skip first line with adding of PPA.

Comment: Thank you for your time!
I followed your commands, but still the 'gmp' and 'Qt5Qwt6' cannot be found. Also, all the 'ctest' results are failed.

Comment: Please install all updates to the system, carefully execute all commands from the answer and then share the error log with `dpkg -l; apt-cache policy; grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"; sudo apt-get update` to pastebin. I can't get any issues (it says *Found GMP: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so* on next line after *No package 'gmp' found*; *No package 'Qt5Qwt6' found*, but next line is *QWT Version: 6.1.3*)  on fresh minimal 18.04.6 LTS VM with only one PPA (with GRC) added. Do you have custom local Qt installation?

Comment: You are right. The GMP is found as you described.  Regarding the Qt installation, I found the Qt creator, Qt 5 Designer, and Qt 5 linguist installed on my PC (it is shared PC). 

This is the resulted list related to the Qt:
-- Python checking for PyQt5 - found
-- Checking for module 'Qt5Qwt6'
--   No package 'Qt5Qwt6' found
-- QWT Version: 6.1.3
-- Found Qwt: /usr/lib/libqwt-qt5.so  
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.13") found components:  doxygen missing components:  dot

Comment: After following your commands from the answer and then running the commands in the comment respectively:

dpkg -l
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)apt-cache policy

Comment: grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"   ;

/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted ;

/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties ; 

/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe; 

/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse;

Comment: For the previous command there more results but I cannot add them because of the limited space.

 sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.8/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Use pastebin.com for long outputs. I can't read your last comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131052/discussion-between-wesam-amiri-and-n0rbert).